# Strange error(dereferencing pointer to incomplete type)

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel

```
void get_cwd(char* buf)
{
    char *result;

  current->fs->pwd;
    result = get_dentry_path(current->fs->pwd);

    memcpy(buf, result, strlen(result)+1);

    kfree(result);
}
```

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

The error points to current->fs->pwd;

includes:

```
#include <asm/stat.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/file.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/current.h>
#include <linux/path.h>
```

If I type current->fs; on 5th line gcc don't give error on this line. The problem is with `pwd` field.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the definition of current...

Comment: It is included: #include <asm/current.h>

Comment: Could you add info on how `current` type is defined and how `fs` type is defined? Also you could split line into two to find out which dereferencing fails.

Comment: It is part of linux kernel and it seems that it is defined in asm/current.h but there is strange code for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is kind of stale but I ran into the same issue again trying to implement *getcwd* in kernel v2.6.33. Since this is the most relevant result that comes up when searched for "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type current->fs", it would be good to have the solution for future reference.

The solution is to include both of these headers:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>
```

Answer (score 6):

`error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` means that you're attempting to access data within an opaque data structure. An opaque data structure is usually just a `typedef` in a header file (.h*), with the real definition in the implementation file (.c*) and only accessible to the implementation. This is used to hide the implementation details and only provide access to the elements via the interface API provided by the header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Answer (score 2):

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/include/linux/fs_struct.h#L11 -- this should work; **current** should be a pointer to **struct task struct**, which should contain a pointer to **struct fs_struct fs**, which should contain **struct path pwd**.  Perhaps you need to include **fs_struct.h** so you can see the contents of **struct fs_struct**.

Comment: I am not c-programmer but I need this problem to be resolved. This way I am trying to debug and localize the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add `#include <linux/fs_struct.h>` as this answer suggests?

Comment: Thanks! The problem was on new kernel versions.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the error message and your experiments obviously mean that `current->fs` is a pointer to an incomplete type. That's all there is to it. Why do you consider it "strange"?

Comment: Look carefully for typos too.  I just spent an hour on this problem and found "struct duprec" vs "struct duperec".   They were far enough apart in the code that I couldn't see both at once, either could have been right.