# Access the structure pointer member of a structure pointer

Tags: c, linux, driver

Hello All,

```
    struct pwm_bl_data {
        struct pwm_device       *pwm;
        struct device           *dev;
        unsigned int            period;
        unsigned int            lth_brightness;
        int                     (*notify)(struct device *,
                                  int brightness);
        int                     (*check_fb)(struct device *, struct fb_info*);
    };

    static int pwm_backlight_update_status(struct backlight_device *bl)
    {
        struct pwm_bl_data *pb = dev_get_drvdata(&bl->dev);
        int brightness = bl->props.brightness;
        int max = bl->props.max_brightness;
        int ret;
        if (bl->props.power != FB_BLANK_UNBLANK)
            brightness = 0;

        if (bl->props.fb_blank != FB_BLANK_UNBLANK)
            brightness = 0;

        if (pb->notify)
            brightness = pb->notify(pb->dev, brightness);

        printk("THE PWM ID COMING in UPDATE STATUS IS %d\n", *(pb->pwm->pwm_id));
        . . .
```

I am trying to access the `pwm_id`, which is an `unsigned int` member of `struct pwm` but I am getting

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: You need to include a header in which the structure is defined

Comment: There is no `struct pwm` in the code you show.

Comment: It is defined in another c file called pwm.c

Comment: Create a pwm.h header file to share this `struct pwm_device *pwm;`.

Comment: It is there already defined as struct pwm_device;

Comment: There are pretty number of questions about `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`. E.g., [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693393/strange-errordereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type). In short, your code should see **definition** of `struct pwm_device` for being able to access its fields. As J.Piquard notes, you may create `pwm.h` header file with this definition, and include this file into every source which needs the definition.